# 2D array using **p

Tags: arrays, 2d

```
int main()
{
   int ** ary;
   ary = new int*[3];
   int i;
for(i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
     ary[i] = new int[4];
}

for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
    delete [] ary[i];
}
delete [] ary;


    return 0;
}
```

It looks pretty simple, but I got an error when compling it with code blocks.
error: 'new' undeclared (first use in this function)
Any suggestions are appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you compiling with a C++ compiler?  'new' is a C++ keyword.  If you're compiling in C, use malloc() instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The compiler is GNU GCC Compiler. Yesterday another similar c code works fine which is without the "delete" part. Today something goes weird. I'm a newie and followed some vedio on youtube. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=868qXWoGS9E

Comment: I'm saying that 'new' and 'delete' are for C++, and not for C.  Try something like this:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

int main(void) {
 int ** ary;
 ary = (int**)malloc(3*sizeof(int*));
 int i;
 for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
 {
  ary[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
 }

 for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
 {
  free(ary[i]);
 }
 free(ary);


 return 0;
}

Comment: I tried and it worked. But I can still not believe that I created project using c on code blocks yesterday, and I made an mistake using "new", however it works fine yesterday But not today. Thanks for your help.